# Should I assume ReactDOM.createRoot was done instead of ReactDOM.render in React 18?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a React component that can be used by any React application, I want to use the new features from React 18 like concurrency, now because my component is not responsible for the `ReactDOM.render` vs `ReactDOM.createRoot` my component wont be able to "know" if it can use the new React 18 features.

What's the recommended way to handle this? assume that React is on version 18?

Comment: As every standalone component which is a npm package, add React 18.x as peer dependency.

Comment: yea, but that does not guarantee that the client will use `ReactDOM.createRoot`